# Cancel form submit default behavior jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to submit the form without reloading the page and pass the data to a external php file using $.post. I am having problem on preventing the reload of the page on form submit. How can I cancel the reloading upon clicking the submit button?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#formajax").live("submit", function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("process.php", $this.serialize(), function(data){
                alert("DATA PASSED!");
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>

<form method="post" action="" id="formajax">
    <input type="text" id="samplefield" name="samplefield" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what version of jQuery you're using, but consider moving to .on(), as .live() is deprecated in 1.7. Also, jQuery docs state that .delgate() is preferable to .live() in older versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with what the `live` method does with jQuery, but it seems to be the source of your problems. If you replace `live` with `bind`, in my testing, the page doesn't reload and I get a "DATA PASSED" prompt.

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(e){
                    $("#formajax").bind("submit", function(e){
                            var $this = $(this);
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.post("index.php", $this.serialize(), function(data){
                                    alert("DATA PASSED!");
                            });
                            return false;
                    })
            })
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="" id="formajax">
            <input type="text" id="samplefield" name="samplefield" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: That's weird, I've tried to replace the live with bind before, but to no avail. By the way, thank you for the effort!